# Extremely large document, how to improve loading as more than 50% is not shown at a singular time?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

My page, of which you can view [here](https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/InteractiveMap/implementing.html), by the time of completion, is going to be an extremely large document and may time out upon trying to load the page. At the bottom of this page, there is a slider, of which is currently not working due to the Javascript being rewritten, however you can still see 6 images/links.

1. Load the page and the current slider and tabs under the #Current section of the #Map-Selection-Info (the side menu) will load as they do at the moment.
2. Upon clicking on a country/continent, the #Current tab will switch and on that tab, there'll be an option to focus in on that country.
3. Upon focusing, I need the current tabs under the #Current section (it is a tab switcher inside of a tab switcher) to load a new set of information and the slider to load a new set images/links.

Without implementing something to load the content, whether it is in Javascript/JQuery or PHP, or whatnot, will hopefully make the page run more smoothly.

My question is how should this content be loaded. The current JQuery code on my page, is the first thing I have really done by myself with JQuery and I don't have a clue what to even search for to do what I personally think how it should be done, I don't even know if this is the best way.

Hopefully you understand what I am explaining, and if you do, I am not asking for any scripts, handouts or whatnot, I simply need to know what is it that I should do, to be able to search for the relevant to be able to more forward.

Best Regards,

Tim

Comment: So load the content with Ajax when it is needed.

Comment: Use Cache .. they are your friend

Comment: So enter the fantastic world of AJAX and asynchronous content loading.

Comment: I think you might also want to search for the term "lazy loading".  It means you only load content when it is necessary and/or when the browser has already taken care of everything else important.  There are a few "lazy load" plugins, but with a little bit of jQuery/AJAX knowledge you can probably roll your own impementation.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, I am currently going through the page @user1569248 has provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out ajax. It helps load content dynamically.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

One possibility would be to have your html for the information, images, and links in one big resources file. What ajax would do is visit that page, find the specified div (by ID, probably), grab the content, and then replace the content you're looking to replace.

Comment: Thank you @user1569248 I will look through the provided page, however it will take some time needing the computers magnifier on at a minimum of x500% so once I've gone through it all, I will possibly leave some feedback.

Comment: I just added more detail to my answer to hopefully provide some context for all of that information.

Comment: AJAX seems to be really amazing, exactly what I need. I have found a very basic example on W3Schools [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load) with gave me more confirmation this is what I need, once again thank you and to anyone whom mentioned AJAX.